# Участник был удален

Tags: поддержка, репутация

Пишет в рейтинге "Участник был удален" и минус 50 баллов. Что это такое и почему рейтинг был удален?

Comment: Может стоит дать ссылку?

Comment: @Other  какую ? На что? Я не знаю какой участник удалился

Comment: Ну народ хочет хлеба и зрелищ в качестве пруфов.

Comment: В справке [написано](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed) об этом. Надо перевод поправить слегка.

Answer (score 4):

Ну там же прям рядом ссылка [подробнее](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed):

[image: скриншот]